# How to concatenate url with a variable everytime a login is made

Tags: javascript, php

The Wordpress site I'm working on:

```
http://www.careersroadmap.com/
```

After submission of a registration form, I have to redirect to this URL:

```
http://careertest.edumilestones.com/access-login-api.php?
```

However, during the redirect, I have to pass this variable to the URL:

```
category=2123&channel_id=371&cd=89&age=371&access_code=accesscodehere
```

So the final destination URL will be:

```
http://careertest.edumilestones.com/access-login-api.php?category=2123&channel_id=371&cd=89&age=371&access_code=accesscodehere
```

The access_code variable will change for each user that logs in.

I tried an AJAX call using the code below:

```
<script>

var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
startButton.addEventListener("click", getApiFunction());

function getApiFunction(){
    var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myRequest.open('GET', 'http://careertest.edumilestones.com/access-login-api.php?category=2123&channel_id=371&cd=89&age=371&access_code=accesscodehere');
    myRequest.onload= function(){
        var myData = JSON.parse(this.response);
    };
    myRequest.send();
};

</script>
```

After trying the above code, I got the CORS policy error.

How do I accomplish this with Javascript or PHP??

Comment: @SAVe [Please don't introduce "thanks" into posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/6296561). It increases the risk of your edit being rejected. Judging by the rest of the edit, I'm assuming you did it to bypass the 6 char edit requirement - please don't. Find actual stuff to edit instead of introducing noise.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could add hidden inputs to the registration form.

Something along those lines:

```
<form action="http://careertest.edumilestones.com/access-login-api.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="category" value="2123">
    <input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="371">
    <input type="hidden" name="cd" value="89">
    <input type="hidden" name="age" value="371">
    <input type="hidden" name="access_code" value="democodesjam12474">
</form>
```

> A hidden field lets web developers include data that cannot be seen or modified by users when a form is submitted.

Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp

Comment: thank you for responding, but can I insert code to change the value of access code when a new user submits the form??

Comment: You can use Php to get the access code, and put it as the 'value' field of your hidden input.  Like this: `<input type="hidden" name="age" value="<?php echo getAccessCode(); ?>">`

Comment: in that case, is it a good idea to insert all the access codes in a table and then retrieve for each form submission?

Comment: You could do that, but I guess it depends on what these `access_codes` are. If they are supposed to be secret, you shouldn't expose them in the URL, but if 
 they aren't then you can use them in URLs and you could add them to an array and retrieve them for each form as you said.

Comment: access_codes are not secret, they are required in the URL to access the page, but these codes have to be dynamically added to the URL after form submission. And a new access_code is to be added for every time the form is submitted.